# LifeRay 7 "cannot find symbol" Maven service-builder

Tags: maven, liferay

Create a json webservice for liferay with:

`mvn -X archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.liferay -DarchetypeArtifactId=com.liferay.project.templates.service.builder -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.7 -DgroupId=com.paygroup -DartifactId=com.paygroup.liferay.templates.service -DinteractiveMode=false -Dauthor=Author`

As a result I got two projects one is an "api" and another is a "service".
The service application has a configuration file (service.xml) that leaves it this way:

```
<service-builder package-path="com.paygroup.liferay.service">
    <namespace>Empresas</namespace>

    <entity local-service="true" name="Empresas" remote-service="true" uuid="true">

        <column name="empresaName" primary="true" type="String" />

        <column name="empresaId" type="long" />

        <column name="convenio1" type="String" />
        <column name="convenio2" type="String" />
        <column name="convenio3" type="String" />

        <column name="descripcion" type="String" />
        <column name="activo" type="boolean" />
        <column name="fecha" type="Date" />

        <order by="asc">
            <order-column name="empresaId" />
        </order>

        <finder name="EmpresaName" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="empresaName" />
        </finder>

        <reference entity="AssetEntry" package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" />
        <reference entity="AssetTag" package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" />
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

Running the service-builder command (`mvn service-builder:build`) works great but when packaging the project with `mvn package` there is a long list of class errors that are not found:

`[ERROR] /media/media/git/GITLAB/demos/liferay/ejemplo-json-webservice/json-webservice/json-webservice-service/src/main/java/com/paygroup/liferay/service/service/persistence/impl/EmpresasPersistenceImpl.java:[38,46]
package com.paygroup.liferay.service.exception does not exist 
[ERROR] /media/media/git/GITLAB/demos/liferay/ejemplo-json-webservice/json-webservice/json-webservice-service/src/main/java/com/paygroup/liferay/service/service/persistence/impl/EmpresasPersistenceImpl.java:[39,42], cannot find symbol 
[ERROR] symbol: class Empresas 
[ERROR] location: package com.paygroup.liferay.service.model`

Why does not the service-builder create these classes?

will the service.xml be misconfigured?

Comment: Have you tried to do an `mvn clean install` on the api project first? So that you service project might be able find the api code from your local repo

Answer (score 0):

you need to run `mvn clean install` on parent project.
ex: project name **abc**. So, you'll get abc-service, abc-api after creating service project. you need to run your command on **abc** project